# PHP cURL Compatibility between Mac and Linux

Tags: php, linux, curl

So on my Mac, I use the localhost Apache built in to test my PHP. After seeing that this code **does** work locally, I upload it to my own Linux server running *Apache 2.2* and *PHP 5*.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $login_url = 'https://logon.do';
    $post_data = "username=" . urlencode($_POST['username']) . "&password=" . urlencode($_POST['password']);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $postResult, $m);
    parse_str($m[1], $cookies);

    $data = $cookies['JSESSIONID'];
}
?>
```

I have checked already that the data is being posted properly and the URL is formed correctly. I am not sure if it is failing within the cURL, as I have no errors. Am I missing a package I need to install or do I need to change my code now that it is on a Linux versus my local Mac version?

Comment: Any messages in the error log? By the way, you could encode the `POST` variables using `urlencode()` to make sure they are correct.

Comment: @jeroen I do not have an error log at `/etc/php.ini` and there are no errors either in the Chrome console.

Comment: The Apache error log?

Comment: @jeroen Just checked, no errors are shown by Apache.